# Rails Mail Server got an error ( Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired) )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I'm struggling an error in rails mail server .. Lately, my mail is working well but yesterday I tried to send email again .. I got an error of `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30579ms` ( `Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired)` ) .. I already searched some possible solutions but nothings worked with it.

Development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
      :port                 => 25,
      :domain               => 'localhost:3000',
      :user_name            => 'my_email@gmail.com',
      :password             => 'my_password',
      :authentication       => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true,
      :tls                  => true
  }
```

Comment: What happens if you try to change the port to `465`?

Comment: Accidental “network unreachable”? That simply could happen if smth went wrong with your network connection.

Comment: @Drenmi Yes sir, also tried the port `587` .. nothings happen got the same error ..

Comment: How could I fixed this?